# how to encode data column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have a data set with following column:

[image: Data preview]

As shown in the image, the Level 1 is univariate while level 2 bivariate and level 3 is multivariate. There level 3 may repeat for different level 2. How can I encode these variables together in pandas, so that  ***Ingredients+Foods+Container*** columns is combined to one category?

I want to analyze which vendor provides price efficient products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) with joined all columns together:

```
df['new'] = pd.factorize(df['Level 1'] + df['Level 2'] + df['Level 3'])[0]
```